# Unable to Run a query on IBM db2

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-cloud

I have just started with IBM db2 and am running an sql query which I suppose is right. But nothing is happening when I hit the run button. Could anyone help?

```
Create table INSTRUCTOR
CREATE TABLE INSTRUCTOR
  (ins_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
   lastname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
   firstname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
   city VARCHAR(15), 
   country CHAR(2)
   );
```

Under the result area it is displaying "waiting" and nothing actually happens.

Comment: Why there stand doubled `Create table INSTRUCTOR` statement ?

Comment: addition to the duplicate statement, I guess may be the db server is down/no connectivity and it displays "waiting"..

Comment: You should say what tool you are using. I.e. you say you "hit the run button" but in what tool/interface? There are many way of running a query on Db2

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CREATE TABLE INSTRUCTOR
(  ins_id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
   lastname  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
   firstname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
   city      VARCHAR(15), 
   country   CHAR(2)
 );
```

That should work for you assuming that you have `;` set as the statement terminator in your query interface (it is the default in most SQL interfaces for Db2).

Alternatively, it might be that your CREATE TABLE is waiting for a lock on the system catalog. You can look at currently held lock with `MON_GET_LOCKS` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056428.html